# Application use case of Reverse Level Order Traversal

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Similar to how level order traversal in tree represents BFS in graph theory and thus has various applications such as finding shortest path between 2 nodes, what could be a use case of finding reverse of level order traversal. 
For example:

Level Order Traversal of given tree is {1,2,3,4,5} i.e. level 0 to level n.

Reverse of Level Order Traversal for following tree would be {4,5,2,3,1} i.e. starting from level n to level 0.

[image]